# Link a website (kraken.com) using API on Android Studio

Tags: json, api, android-studio, httprequest

I was wondering how I could link my application to kraken.com server.

For example, making a login activity that sends the username and password to the server and if it's correct, open another activity.

The kraken's API is given by the following link: https://www.kraken.com/help/api

The problem is that I don't know how this API exactly works. How can I make HTTP Request and what is json? Consider I'm new in this area (API).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So firstly, JSON stand for Javascript Object Notation, it's a syntax for exchanging or storing data.

*I'm assuming you're using Java since you're using Android Studio.*

Looking at Kraken's API page: https://www.kraken.com/help/api#example-api-code
They don't currently have support a 3rd party Java Library for API access. So you would be looking a using a RESTful approach.

Here is an example of how to use that approach in Java: https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restfull-java-client-with-java-net-url/